# How to make a date filter using column from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, datetime

I have two datasets that I need to create a filter looking at 90 days back in df1 from the `target_date` in df2.

Example:

DF1

```
 id       name       start_date      end_date      team
1234   John Smith     1/1/2022       2/1/2022      Sales
1234   John Smith     2/1/2022       4/2/2022      Sales 
1234   John Smith     4/2/2022       8/4/2022      Admin
4321   Derek Jeter    7/23/2022      8/12/2022     Tech
4321   Derek Jeter    8/12/2022      12/12/2022    Tech
5678   Joe Dirt       1/23/2023      3/21/2023     HR
5678   Joe Dirt       3/21/2023      5/4/2023      HR
5678   Joe Dirt       5/4/2023       7/2/2023      HR
```

DF2

```
case  team    emp_name      target_date      
100   Sales  J.Smith          7/1/2022 
101   Tech   Jeter, Derek     1/17/2023
102   HR     Joe Dirt         7/1/2023
```

What I would like to see is the `target_date` in DF2 is used as the base for the filtering on `end_date` in DF1I.So for example if the `target_date` is 10/1/2023 the `end_date` would have to be on or before 7/1/2023. A dataframe would then look like this:

```
 id       name         start_date        end_date       team
1234    John Smith      1/1/2022          2/1/2022      Sales 
1234    John Smith      2/1/2022          4/2/2022      Sales  
4321    Derek Jeter     7/23/2022         8/12/2022     Tech
5678    Joe Dirt        1/23/2022         3/21/2023     HR
```

this is what I have tried:

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
   threshold_date = row['target_date'] - timedelta(days = 90)
   filtered_rows = df[(df['end_date'] <= threshold_date)]
filtered_dfs.append(filtered_rows)
df = pd.concat(filtered_dfs,ignore_index = True)
```

I think I need to find a way to match the names, but I am not sure.

Comment: You must convert the date columns to a datetime dtype with `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: See [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FJxE.png). The code works fine once the columns a converted to datetime dtypes.

Comment: `df1[['start_date', 'end_date']] = df1[['start_date', 'end_date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)` and `df2.target_date = pd.to_datetime(df2.target_date)`